# How to place a Unity monobehavior object in 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

So I know how to instantiate an object; however, I have created a terrain that is not flat and am implementing physics on all objects. I will be spawning objects at locations but they need to be initialized on top of the terrain (not above). I can use a raycast from a very high y-axis position and cast downward to see for an intersection with the terrain and then use that position + half of the object y-dimension (so that it sits on top of the terrain); however, the terrain is oddly shaped and if the piece of terrain I want to put the object on is shaped concavely upward, part of the object that I create will be underneath the ground. Another way I have been thinking is to create the object quite a bit above the terrain and allow gravity to drop it down to the height where it sits on top of the terrain naturally; however, this sucks... I want it to be immediate and I think that there definitely should be a better way of doing this than what I have in mind.

ASCII Drawing:

```
       ______
      |      |
      |      |
      |______|
         |
-        |
  -      |     -
    -    |    -
      -  |   -
      * -V  -*
          --
```

The Box represents the object, the hyphens below represent the terrain underneath. The * represents the potential overlapping volume of the object with the terrain.

The line above ending with a 'V' represents the SampleHeight idea. It checks the height at that particular point as it takes in only a Vector3 as an input. If I place the object (with an offset) so that the bottom surface of the object touches the point below the 'V', the lower edges will still be going through the terrain.

Comment: That can be done with `Terrain.SampleHeight`. See duplicated question.

Comment: I looked at the posted question; however, SampleHeight does not contain an area. It calculates using a specific point (which I can obtain too just by raycasting). The issue is what if I have a concave up surface. If I place the object exactly where the SampledHeight is, the edges of the object will be going through the terrain.

Comment: I think you should try this before making further comments. It will save both of us time. You can apply offset to it like I did in the answer.

Comment: I can try it; I just really don't think that it will work. It also doesn't take into account the difference in rotation of the object when placed so that it adheres to the surface. (Getting the normal of a point also won't do me any good as there is an area that can be affecting the position and rotation of the object.)

Comment: Yes, the duplicate question answers your question. All you need to do is little thinking. Instead of calculating `SampleHeight` from center of the object, calculate it from 4 corners of the object and adjust the rotation.

Comment: No it doesn't imagine an irregular shape, how do you know what part of project from? You have to sample every single point. What if your object was dropped right on a flag pole? Your method of calculating would make the object go right through, as the flagpole's collider will be inside the vertices. Stop assuming things... I honestly don't know how much more unhelpful you and the incompetent person who closed my question are.